# Best way to compare two classes (Users and Holidays) and create a list of Users who have not created an instance of the Holiday class with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I apologize if this is badly worded, I'm a relatively new English speaker.

I have 2 classes: Holidays and ApplicationUsers

The Holidays class has a foreign key of the ApplicationUserId taken from the ApplicationUsers class

I'm trying to create a new list of Users who have not created instances of the Holiday class

Below is the code I am trying to use:

```
NotBooked = await _db.ApplicationUser.Include(i => i.Holidays).Where(i => i.Id != i.Holidays.ApplicationUserId).ToListAsync();
```

I'm struggling to create a list of Users whose ApplicationUser ForeignKey is not present within the Holidays items.

Is there a better way to do this?

Many Thanks

Comment: If you want users without holidays then this should do `db.Applicationuser.Where(u => !u.Holidays.Any())`

Comment: You need to use `Where(i => i.Holidays.Count()>0)`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya That seems to be the opposite because they want users that do not have holidays.

Comment: Oh... My mistake...`Where(i => i.Holidays.Count() == 0)` this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If a user does not have a holiday, then there will be no Holiday record for it in Holidays table, so:

```
_db.ApplicationUser.Where(u => !u.Holidays.Count() == 0);
```